# Compiling Java GUI makes system hang

Tags: java, user-interface, system, freeze

So I have this really, really weird problem that I've had for a while now, but could never find an answer for, so I'm posting here:

Whenever I have a Java project that involves GUI's, and I mean any kind of GUI with any kind of element, on compile my computer basically freezes for an entire minute before it pops up the compiled GUI. These aren't even programming intensive GUI's - even the most basic ones make my system hang. This is a pain because even frameworks using Java GUI elements (like Processing), now take forever to compile, and that really doesn't help for quick and easy testing.

Note that this isn't just my PC - my laptop and every other machine I've tried to install Java on and test with suffers the same fate. However, this isn't a universal problem, since PC's at my university compile GUI stuff that takes me a full minute in about a second.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Java twice (both JRE and JDK), but to no avail, and there's nothing I can find on the internet suited to this particular issue. I don't know if it's an issue with my machines or the Java installation or bad juju or something, but it's making stuff almost impossible, as well as impossibly frustrating to test.

So please, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you should mention the exact JDK versions and platforms you have tried (for example: the output of `java -version`, your OS name and version, and the amount of RAM in your system); while you're at it, provide source for a minimal self-contained program that exhibits the problem, and tell us how long it takes to compile under your setup.

Comment: This problem occured under JDK 1.6 and 1.7 64 bit and 32 bit, on Windows 7 SP1, PC's with 8GB DDR3 RAM. Unfortunately, posting code might be a hassle since even my small GUIs have a lot of functionality code in the back. Again, I don't know it's a GUI thing so much as a system thing, as the same GUIs work fine on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe using some deprecated elements regarding your version of JDK? I would double check this, but it is a curious case.

Comment: It's definitely not a deprecation issue - I tested some of my GUI's on a friend's PC with the same JDK version and compilation was flawless.